# how to replace some string(s) from a source string which shouldn't be changed upper/lowercase of source string

Tags: c#

i want to replace some string(s) from a source string. so that shouldn't be changed upper/lowercase of source string. how i can do this? I'm using Replace .NET string type method such below:

```
var source = "Sadegh";
var word = "sadegh";
var replaced = source.Replace(word, "<strong>" + word + "</strong>");
```

and replace is: **sadegh** but i want **Sadegh**

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to have the string in Title case ?

Comment: exactly no! in both according to source string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2004/02/11/71188.aspx

String.Replace is not good for that. Regex replace is okay.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a regular expression. I'm at work so I unfortunately can't take the time to write it for you, but the tester at regexlib is very helpful in testing regexes :-)

http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

Comment: I tend to prefer RegexHero, http://regexhero.net/tester/, for fast interactive Regex testing. Doesn't require postback, so it's more immediate feedback.

Answer (score 0):

very well, i'm have code to doing that i want.

```
 string title = "Google google GOOGLE News";
 string pat = "google";
 string res = title;
 foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(title, pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
     res = Regex.Replace(res, m.ToString(), "<strong>" + m + "</strong>", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

and output is **Google** ***google*** ***GOOGLE*** News